# How can I download the cisco running config to my C drive's folder?

Tags: windows, networking, configuration, cisco, router

I am going to download the running config from the cisco router.

I have tried the following command, but it needs to change the account's privilege level to 15 for downloading the running config. I don't want to change anything about the running-config.

```
pscp.exe -scp user@ip:system:running-config new_config
```

How can I download the running config to my c drive? Is there any other method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are two ways I can think of to do this: `1.` Show the running config and then copy and paste it into Notepad (or whatever). `2.` Use TFTP to download it.

Comment: Additionally, it looks to me like you're trying to copy the running config to the startup config, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I cannot set up the tftp server, as my network environment is in NAT mode. And the config is too long to show them all, I cannot copy and paste in a short time. Is there other method?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `pscp` I assume you are using PuTTY.

1. Enable logging in PuTTY.

   [image]
2. Show the running config
3. Use your preferred text editor to copy the config out of the log file.